# Interview Preparation

Tags: interviewing

Is it in general best not to "over-prepare" for a job interview? Given a choice between sufficient sleep and preparing (e.g. for a technical interview), what are some general recommendations?

Comment: How will you function if you don't get sufficient sleep?  I know most people, including me, will not be able to tackle the more challenging problems.  So if you expect a bunch of canned interview questions, asking for quick answers that can be memorized, perhaps it's worth foregoing some sleep.

Comment: @Chan-HoSuh - don't you think your comment is really an answer?

Comment: I don't think it is ever possible to "over prepare" for an interview...

Comment: If you're at the point where you consider it "over-preparing" isn't it by definition time to stop (or do something else)?

Comment: @JeffO Perhaps.  You wrote a better answer than I would have anyway!

Comment: @Chan-HoSuh - That's OK. There's usually more than one good answer.

Answer (score 5):

If there are specific things you need to know and you're just going to regurgitate them in the interview, you can probably get by with little sleep just for one day. Hopefully, you're not being asked to play some sort of technical trivia game.

Many interviews may want deep answers about your past experiences and ways you would handle other hypothetical situations that require deeper thinking. I wouldn't want to be too tired for this type of interview.

Sleep is important. [The Corporate Athlete Advantage](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0977877655) is a book containing a lot research in this area.

Determine what type of interview you think it is. I would at least make sure I got a modest amount of sleep, but that's because I don't see cramming some facts in my head for an hour or two is going to make much difference. I want to have  a lot of energy for an interview.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it in general best not to "over-prepare" for a job interview?

It is best to be as prepared as you can. It's not really possible to be "over-prepared".

> Given a choice between sufficient sleep and preparing (e.g. for a
>   technical interview), what are some general recommendations?

That's a false dilemma. Nobody would ever advise anyone to get insufficient sleep, just as nobody would advise going without food or water in order to prepare for an interview.

Get enough sleep - every day, not just when you are preparing for a test or interview.

Use your free time in your waking hours to prepare for your interview.

In general, you want to understand and be conversant in the technical aspects of the new job, understand the company, and be very conversant on your background - with a particular emphasis on whatever is contained in your resume and cover letter and with anything in your background that is particularly relevant to the new job.

Answer (score 0):

If it's in-person, sleep should absolutely come first. Being sleep-deprived not only tanks your mental agility and recall but your mood and appearance too, and being personable counts a lot even in technical interviews. If you've got your mind in full working order, you should be able to respond thoughtfully even to questions you don't know the answer to, which still counts for a lot. Really, a lot of times, showing you've got critical thinking skills is just as important if not moreso than knowing tech trivia.

If it's just a phone screen, being a little sleep deprived would be more acceptable, but being a total zombie on the phone isn't going to do you any favors either. You're still going to answer more slowly and clumsily without sleep.

Either way, next time, make sure you do your studying and practice well ahead of time so there's no dilemma. Being confident and relaxed really helps a lot with interviews.